# 20 monitors to one Mac

Tags: multiple-monitors

I'm trying to make one giant display screen out of 20 Hanns G monitors. Ideally they would be run from one mac that would change based on who is presenting that day (i.e. plug and play system). I have no knowledge of video/cables/computer configuration so I'm looking for a very spelled out answer. I found an application for mac called ArraySync which I will probably end up using for the video output. I've seen the words "splitter" and "adapter" but don't know exactly what I need for so many monitors. Currently have an AVG to AVG cable for all monitors... nothing else.

Thank you in advance for your help!!

Comment: What is an AVG cable?

Comment: Multiple copies of the same image or one combined image spanning all monitors as if they were one giant monitor?

Comment: @Synetech: I'm assuming it's a VGA cable that scrambles the signals. ;-)

Comment: @DennisWilliamson, that’s what I assumed, but since I don’t use Mac, I figured there may be some sort of Mac-specific thing (though Googling seems to indicate probably not).

Answer (score 3):

Most likely what you will need is a video wall controller device such as one by [Avenview](http://www.google.com/products/catalog?hl=en&cp=12&gs_id=z&xhr=t&q=video%20wall%20controller&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&biw=1188&bih=723&wrapid=tljp1342207629975018&um=1&ie=UTF-8&tbm=shop&cid=14950440100912640305&sa=X&ei=k3YAUIGdBKrd6wHR0aD4Bg&sqi=2&ved=0CHEQ8wIwAg), [Cinemassive](http://www.cinemassivedisplays.com/video-wall-controller/), or the Aventura [XPanse](http://www.aventuracctv.com/Xpanse-Video-Wall-System/).  Even with the use of a number of splitter devices, it is unlikely that the Mac by itself is capable of being set up to control such a large array of monitors by itself.

Comment: Cinemassive is a shady company and I'd stay away from them.